# Detected object boundries, wrong placement?

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

Iam using a sample object detection from PyImageSearch and I modified it a little bit.  It basically uses DNN CAFFE from openCV. It reads the video and does detections on it.

The problem is that the detected boundries and boxes are drawn on the wrong position. It seems it is detecting correct objects but things are off. I have a feeling it is something to do with blobFromImage as it normalizes things.
Here is the code

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"], args["model"])

# load the input image and construct an input blob for the image
# by resizing to a fixed 300x300 pixels and then normalizing it
# (note: normalization is done via the authors of the MobileNet SSD
# implementation)
print (args["video"])
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])
cv2.namedWindow('Stream',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow('Stream', (300,300))
time.sleep(2.0)
while True:
    # read the next frame from the video stream and resize it
    ret, image = video_capture.read() 
    if ret != True:
        break
    dim = (300, 300)
    frame=cv2.resize(image,dim)
    (w, h, c) = image.shape
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(image, (300, 300)), 0.007843, (300, 300), 127.5)

    # pass the blob through the network and obtain the detections and
    # predictions
    print("[INFO] computing object detections...")
    net.setInput(blob)
    detections = net.forward()

    # loop over the detections
    for i in np.arange(0, detections.shape[2]):
        # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with the
        # prediction
        confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]

        # filter out weak detections by ensuring the `confidence` is
        # greater than the minimum confidence
        if confidence > args["confidence"]:
            # extract the index of the class label from the `detections`,
            # then compute the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding box for
            # the object
            idx = int(detections[0, 0, i, 1])
            box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
            (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")

            # display the prediction
            label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(CLASSES[idx], confidence * 100)
            print("[INFO] {}".format(label))
            cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY),
                COLORS[idx], 2)
            y = startY - 15 if startY - 15 > 15 else startY + 15
            cv2.putText(image, label, (startX, y),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, COLORS[idx], 2)
    print("Done")
    cv2.imshow('Frame', image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
# show the output image
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.waitKey(0)
```